# Wrap Text in Text Editor?

Tags: text-editor

I would like to use the text editor to add comments in my blend files.  I would like the text to wrap so that it will automatically fit to the size of the text editor window.  Is there a way I can do that **without code**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Text editor header go to *View > Word Wrap*.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer man!